# VirtualBox screen resolution

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, resolution, osx-elcapitan

I'm running Windows 10 inside VirtualBox 5.1.18 on OS X 10.11.6 and after installing Guest Additions to enable bidirectional c/p the screen resolution has shrank to 800x600 and I managed to increase it to 1024x768. Even though it brings some memories of the times when I was young and restless it won't allow me to do any serious work in Visual Studio. 
First time I installed them trough virtual CD-ROM and second time manually by downloading the right version from the official page.
How to fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this will help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221638/installed-snow-leopard-on-virtualbox-but-cant-install-guest-additions/221639#221639

Comment: @DavidC. It is actually the other way around but thank you!